# Meteor.users adding additional fields to documents not working properly

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm not sure what's wrong but following the documentation on how to grab additional fields from the server here:

`return Meteor.users.find({_id: this.userId}, {fields: {'other': 1, 'things': 1}});`

What ends up happening is that it only publishes the two fields `other and things` instead of the default fields of `emails, profile, username` and `other, things`.

This is what I have return `Meteor.users.find({username: username}, {fields: {'status': 1});`

So what ends up happening is that the client is only receiving two fields `_id, and status`. I don't want to manually add all the 'default' fields to each and every publish function, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You could reason the other way around by EXCLUDING the fields you don't want to publish : `fields:{a:0,b:0}`, be aware that you can't mix inclusion and exclusion.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to apply DRY principle then simply create defaultInclusionFields:

```
var defaultInclusionFields = function() {
  return {
    emails:1,
    profile:1,
    username:1
  };
}
```

and extend `defaultInclusionFields()` using underscore with your custom fields ('other', 'status', ... ):

```
Meteor.users.find(
  {username: username},
  {fields: _.extend(defaultInclusionFields(),{"other":1,"status":1})
);
```

Note that you can not mix inclusions and exclusions.

Comment: Note `_.extend` is in-place, so the existing `defaultInclusionFields` will be modified, which probably isn't what you want.